# Created openwhisk action but shows in guest as private java so can't call it

Tags: openwhisk

Trying to follow directions, I created an action in the vagrant image (e.g., after vagrant ssh) using this command:

```
wsk action create ProcessFuzzyMatch /vagrant/ildMicroServices-1.0.jar --main com.xxx.micro.services.ProcessFuzzyMatch
```

and I could see it was created:

```
wsk action list
actions
/guest/ProcessFuzzyMatch                                               private java
```

however guest isn't listed as a package:

```
wsk package list /whisk.system
packages
/whisk.system/weather                                                  shared
/whisk.system/combinators                                              shared
/whisk.system/websocket                                                shared
/whisk.system/watson-translator                                        shared
/whisk.system/samples                                                  shared
/whisk.system/watson-speechToText                                      shared
/whisk.system/watson-textToSpeech                                      shared
/whisk.system/slack                                                    shared
/whisk.system/github                                                   shared
/whisk.system/utils                                                    shared
```

and attempts to call the action via curl fail with authentication errors but this doesn't seem to be related to the request headers. Instead I guess it is related to the private java nature of the action I registered. I believe this because I can't use the wsk command to show the summary information for the action I'd registered:

```
wsk package get --summary /whisk.system/guest/ProcessFuzzyMatch
error: Unable to get package 'guest/ProcessFuzzyMatch': The requested resource could not be found. (code 364)
```

Is the proper sequence to first create a package then use that package when registering my action?

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Running the build from today, July 17, 2017 on a MacOS version 10.12.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer turned out as a result of following all the other posts recommendations and trying different approaches. It took a while because I had to port all the file based functions to call Cloudant instead and because of the size of artifacts to be loaded and an issue with their attachments API in Java I had to use a workaround (because the data field returned empty).

I tried using the --web=true to avoid the security issues and that got me very close. However, while I got back a reply with 200 response code, the payload was empty (Content-Length: 0). So, I used the wsk invoke action with -v I was able to see how the call was being made locally within the vagrant VM, and was then able to get it to work from outside the VM.

Basically, these were the steps I followed:
    wsk package create ild 
to create my own package which becomes a child of /guest as shown with the command:

```
wsk package list
/guest/ild
```

Then I created my action based on the jar build using gradle (so it includes all dependent classes other than gson.JsonObject since that is already in the runtime environment).

```
wsk action create /guest/ild/ProcessFuzzyMatch /vagrant/ildMicroServices-1.0.jar --main com.xxx.ild.micro.services.ProcessFuzzyMatch --web true
```

Because my service expected a JsonObject containing text and workspaceID I ran the following command in the vagrant VM:

```
 wsk action invoke -v -br ild/ProcessFuzzyMatch -p "text" "borken window" -p "workspaceID" "bc3d43ab-1529-41c8-8571-b7155e53e3ff"
```

And this showed the correct response. By examining the request headers I could see how the action was being referenced so I could then create a shell script to point to the host 192.168.33.13 from outside the VM.

The working shell scripts is shown below:

```
#! /bin/bash
curl -s -v -k https://192.168.33.13/api/v1/namespaces/guest/actions/ild/ProcessFuzzyMatch?blocking=true \
-H "Authorization: Basic MjNiYzQ2YjEtNzFmNi00ZWQ1LThjNTQtODE2YWE0ZjhjNTAyOjEyM3pPM3haQ0xyTU42djJCS0sxZFhZRnBYbFBrY2NPRnFtMTJDZEFzTWdSVTRWck5aOWx5R1ZDR3VNREdJd1A=" \
-X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"text":"borken window","workspaceID":"bc3d43ab-1529-41c8-8571-b7155e53e3ff"}'
```

The -X POST is not needed as POST is assumed. The Authorization was copied from what I'd seen in the headers from the version run on the localhost (in the VM) but it is the Base64 encoding of the ~/openwhisk/ansible/files/auth.guest content (when in the VM via "vagrant ssh" command). This could also have been passed as is using the -u parameter to curl.

In theory, the authentication should not have been required since the --web=true was used when registering the action, but I found it was needed when calling into the VM from outside. Without the header, it returns this error:

```
{
    "error": "The resource requires authentication, which was not supplied with the request",
    "code": 2259
    * Connection #0 to host 192.168.33.13 left intact
 }
```

I believe the key to getting the external call to work was providing the proper URI before the package/action name and ensuring the blocking=true parameter was passed:

```
https://192.168.33.13/api/v1/namespaces/guest/actions/
```

I will up vote all the other replies as they all helped me figure out what was required.

Comment: Glad you sorted it. The key thing is that there are two different URLs you can call for an action with `--web true`: `/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/actions/...` and `/api/v1/web/{namespace}/...`.  The first one requires auth as it's the private API (works without `--web true`) and the second one does not as it's the public facing one that is created when you do `--web true`.

Answer (score 2):

As you have a local build, `guest` is your default namespace name.  The package is `default` (aka `_`) as you didn't specify one. You can find the name of your namespace using:

```
 wsk namespace list
```

It's labelled private as it's yours and not published to the world.

You can invoke your action with:

```
wsk action invoke ProcessFuzzyMatch -r
```

If you wanted to put your action in a namespace, called say "demo", you'd use:

```
wsk package create demo
wsk action create demo/ProcessFuzzyMatch /vagrant/ildMicroServices-1.0.jar --main com.xxx.micro.services.ProcessFuzzyMatch
```

You can now invoke your action with:

```
wsk action invoke demo/ProcessFuzzyMatch -r
```

Finally running `wsk activation poll` in a separate terminal window is helpful to see what's going on when you invoke an action.

Comment: I can invoke the action using wsk locally but it is failing with FileNotFoundException for a file that exists and is owned by vagrant:vagrant and read for anyone. Still can't get curl to work to yield even this error...

Comment: You need to zip up all files as the action runs in a docker container so can't see the vagrant filesystem. I'm not sure if the Java action supports zipping files though as usually you provide a jar file that is presumed to have all that's needed.

Comment: Still can't curl to it either locally (via localhost) or from the hosting system via 192.168.33.13...

Comment: To curl, you need to make it a web action: add `--web true` to your `wsk action create` or `wsk action update` command. Then try: `curl -i http://192.168.33.13/api/v1/web/guest/default/ProcessFuzzyMatch`

Answer (score 1):

- Have you tried using `/guest/default/ProcessFuzzyMatch` in your url instead of `/guest/ProcessFuzzyMatch`

  `The fully qualified name of the action must include its package name, which is "default" if the action is not in a named package.`
- In case of `authentication errors`, you need to pass the auth as header parameters using `-H`

  `curl -k -H "Authorization: Basic <encoded value>" https://<host>/api/v1/namespaces/guest/default/ProcessFuzzyMatch`
- You can also try to invoke action using `wsk` CLI and see if it is getting invoked or not.

  `wsk -i action invoke ProcessFuzzyMatch --result=true`

Comment: curl -u 23bc46b1-71f6-4ed5-8c54-02:123zO3DGIwP \
    -v -k https://192.168.33.13/api/v1/namespaces/guest/default/ProcessFuzzyMatch \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"text":"borken window","workspaceID":"bc3d43ab-1529-41c8-8571-b7155e53e3ff"}'

Fails with "error": "The requested resource code not be found.","code": 5221

Comment: wsk action list shows it as /guest/ProcessFuzzyMatch

Comment: Are you able to invoke your action from CLI 
`wsk -i action invoke ProcessFuzzyMatch`??

Comment: Yes, however then it gets a FileNotFoundException for a file that is at the specified location with appropriate permissions so I'd asked if OpenWhisk has a sandbox limitation for where it can open files.

Comment: A bit different approach but would you mind deploying your action as a _Web Action_
`wsk -i action update ProcessFuzzyMatch --web true`

check this [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_webactions.html#openwhisk_webactions) for more info

Comment: I tried registering it using --web true which got much closer. I got a 200 reply back with all the expected headers, and the log showed the payload that should have been returned, but instead the payload was empty and content length 0. I did finally get it to work without using the web and will post a solution as both of you helped me get there.

Comment: If you get 200 but no body, and you are using `--web true` flag, then you have to add a `body` tag in your json response object. 
 `{header: application/json,statusCode: 200,body: <expected_output>}`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create a package for your action. Actions in the default package which is what you created will not appear in the package listing.

Also you're listing a `whisk.system` namespace while creating the action in the `guest` namespace.

So if you want to put the action in the `whisk.system` package, you'll need to use that API key and create the package first.

`wsk package create mypkg -u <whisk.system key>`

`wsk action create mypkg/ProcessFuzzyMatch ... -u <whisk.system key>`

Otherwise you the guest key to get the action

`wsk action get ProcessFuzzyMatch --summary`

Or equally

`wsk action get /guest/ProcessFuzzyMatch --summary`

Note that summaries are currently not generated if an action does not have any annotations (see https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/issues/2270).

Comment: Following the directions above, even though I created the package it still gets put under guest so the wsk action list now shows:

    /guest/ild/ProcessFuzzyMatch            private java

Comment: I assume the <whisk.system key> is the content shown when performing:

    cat openwhisk/ansible/files/auth.guest`

when ssh'ed into vagrant.

Comment: This is the whisk.system key https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/ansible/files/auth.whisk.system

Comment: Using that content fails, but using the auth.guest content works, though the package is added under guest (e.g., wsk package list shows it as /guest/myPkg)